# Which option to choose when voting to close a question that is covered in tag info?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, vote-to-close

Sorry if this is a duplicated question (at least I haven't found it yet). I found a question which answer is well covered in the tag info example (it includes a good explanation as well). I just pointed out this but do not know how to vote it to close including the link since it can't be considered as duplicate question.

Question in fact: [How do you create a simple user validation java filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15936999/1065197)

Tag info which resolves the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info (to be precise, this is covered in the Hello world example).

Comment: Sometimes I wish we had an `obvious-answer` close reason. But hey, you can answer it for free rep!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can relate as duplicate **only to other questions**, not wikis, answers or anything else.

Comment: Correct.  Which is why I don't advocate putting General Reference information directly into a tag wiki, but linking to a canonical reference question instead.